# Elasticsearch index design

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I am maintaining a years of user's activity including browse, purchase data. Each entry in browse/purchase is a json object:{item_id: id1, item_name, name1, category: c1, brand:b1, event_time: t1} .

I would like to compose different queries such like getting all customers who browsed item A, and or  purchased item B within time range t1 to t2. There are tens of millions customers.

My current design is to use nested object for each customer:

```
customer1:
       customer_id,id1,
       name: name1,
       country: US,
       browse: [{browseentry1_json},{browseentry2_json},...],
       purchase: [{purchase entry1_json},{purchase entry2_json},...]
```

With this design, I can easily compose all kinds of queries with nested query. The only problem is that it is hard to expire older browse/purchase data: I only wanna keep, for example, a years of browse/purchase data. In this design, I will have to at some point, read the entire index out, delete the expired browse/purchase data, and write them back.

Another design  is to use parent/child structure.
type: user is the parent of type browse and purchase.
type browse will contain each browse entry.
Although deleting old data seems easier with delete by query,  for the above query, I will have to do multiple and/or has_child queries,and it would be much less performant. In fact, initially i was using parent/child structure, but the query time seemed really long. I thus gave it up and tried to switch to nested object.

I am also thinking about using nested object, but break the data into different index(like monthly index) so that I can easily expire old data. The problem with this approach is that I have to query across those multiple indexes, and do aggregation on that to get the distinct users, which I assume will be much slower.(havn't tried yet). One requirement of this project is to be able to give the count of the queries in acceptable time frame.(like seconds) and I am afraid this approach may not be acceptable.

The ES cluster is 7 machines, each 8 cores and 32G memory.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!
Chen

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a customers index I would create a "Browsing" indices (indexes) and a "Purchasing" indices separated by a timespan (EG: Monthly, as you mentioned in your last paragraph). 
In each struct I would add the customer fields. Now you are facing two different approaches:
1. You can add only a reference to the customer (such as id) and make another query to get his details.
2. If you don't have any storage problem you can keep all the customer's data in  each struct.

if this doesn't enough for performance you can combine it with "routing" and save all specific user's data on the same shard. and Elasticsearch won't need to fetch data between shards (you can watch [this video](https://www.elastic.co/videos/big-data-search-and-analytics/) where Shay Benon explains about "user data flow")

Niv

Comment: This is the most natural way of thinking. But how can I do a simple "and" query cross indexes like "who browsed item A, and purchased item B"?

Comment: you can just use commas between indices and mappings. btw i by mistake written different indices but you can put your types ("browsing", "purchasing") as different mappings.